# Checking for a default Constructor using class templates with std::void_t

Tags: c++, c++11, c++17, template-meta-programming

Below is the snippet which is trying to check for the presence of a default constructor at compile time. Compiling this with

```
clang version 11.0.0
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin19.6.0
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin
```

using options `clang++ --std=c++17 -o test_default_ctor test_default_ctor.cpp`

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_default_ctor_1 : std::false_type {}; 

template<typename T>
struct has_default_ctor_1<T, std::void_t<decltype(T())>> : std::true_type {}; 

template<typename T, typename = void>
struct has_default_ctor_2 : std::false_type {}; 

template<typename T>
struct has_default_ctor_2<T, std::void_t<decltype(T{})>> : std::true_type {}; 

struct Test1 {
    Test1() = default;
};

struct Test2 {
    Test2() {}
};

struct Test3 {
    Test3() = delete;
};

int main() {
    static_assert(has_default_ctor_1<Test1>::value, "Test has default ctor");
    static_assert(has_default_ctor_2<Test1>::value, "Test has default ctor");
    static_assert(has_default_ctor_1<Test2>::value, "Test has default ctor");
    static_assert(has_default_ctor_2<Test2>::value, "Test has default ctor");
    static_assert(not has_default_ctor_1<Test3>::value, "Test has default ctor");
    static_assert(not has_default_ctor_2<Test3>::value, "Test has default ctor");
}
```

the output of compilation will be

```
test_default_ctor.cpp:33:5: error: static_assert failed due to requirement '!has_default_ctor_2<Test3, void>::value' "Test has default ctor"
    static_assert(not has_default_ctor_2<Test3>::value, "Test has default ctor");
    ^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
```

The question is why using `()` vs `{}` for constructor call in the template specialization makes it work in one case but not in the other?

Comment: You want to know why `static_assert(not has_default_ctor_1<Test3>::value, "Test has default ctor");` did not fail?

Comment: I want to know why `static_assert(not has_default_ctor_2<Test3>::value, "Test has default ctor");` failed, meaning why `has_default_ctor2...` for that case is true, where the default constructor is deleted

Comment: well I got confused. Perhaps clarify in the question more explicitly what your expectations were. `Test1` and `Test2` are not related to the question and could be removed, right?

Comment: of course they could be removed, i left them in just to show an example. i will clarify. thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> ```
> template<typename T>
> struct has_default_ctor_2<T, std::void_t<decltype(T{})>> : std::true_type {};
> ```

As you are checking whether `T{}` is well-formed, you allow also types which may be initialized by means of aggregate initialization. `Test3` is an aggregate class prior to C++20 as it has no *user-provided* constructor. From [[dcl.fct.def.default]/5](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/dcl.fct.def.default#5) [extract, **emphasis** mine]:

> [...] A function is user-provided if it is user-declared **and not explicitly** defaulted or **deleted on its first declaration.**

For a detailed passage of aggregates over different standard versions, see e.g.:

- [The fickle aggregate](https://dfrib.github.io/the-fickle-aggregate/)

> #### Aggregates in C++20
>
> As of C++20, particularly due to the implementation of [P1008R1](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p1008r1.pdf) (*Prohibit aggregates with user-declared constructors*) most of the frequently surprising aggregate behaviour covered above has been addressed, specifically by no longer allowing aggregates to have *user-**declared*** constructors, a stricter requirement for a class to be an aggregate than just prohibiting *user-provided* constructors.

Comment: what changed in C++20?

Comment: The requirement for being an aggregate became stricter, from no _user-provided_ to no _user-declared_ ctors.

Comment: indeed, adding to `Test3` something like: `Test3(int) {}` makes things work as expected. thanks!